# Sonarqube on windows 10 won't start

Tags: java, windows, logging, jvm, sonarqube

i have a problem with sonarqube 8.0 on windows 10.
in logs directory there are two text file.
sonar.txt contains this

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.11.26 22:06:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-8.0\temp
2019.11.26 22:06:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.11.26 22:06:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-8.0\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-8.0\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-8.0\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-8.0\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
2019.11.26 22:06:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019.11.26 22:07:02 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.11.26 22:07:02 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.11.26 22:07:33 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2019.11.26 22:07:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.11.26 22:07:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

and es.txt contains many lines but I think the important thing is this,

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.jdk.internal.vm.annotation")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running Java 13. Downgrade to Java 11, which is the latest version of Java supported.

SonarQube [prereqs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/) doc is quite clear on the issue.